# Probability of elements in a subset of the original set

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let me try and rephrase the question as an example. I'll use bits since its convenient in this case.

You have 3 bits A, B and C, that have probability `1/2` of being 1 and `1/2` of being 0.

We take $A^{-1}$ as the inverse of A, i.e. $1-A$.

We calculate the following values (all $2^3$ combinations):

$A*B*C\\
A*B*C^{-1}\\
A*B^{-1}*C\\
A*B^{-1}*C^{-1}\\
A^{-1}*B*C\\
A^{-1}*B*C^{-1}\\
A^{-1}*B^{-1}*C\\
A^{-1}*B^{-1}*C^{-1}$

Only one of these will have the end result of `1`, with probability `1/8`, yes?

So say the result is `[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]`. The `1` would be at index `4` and for all indexes `i` it holds that the probability it is `1` is `1/8`, yes?

So now look only at the first `5` indexes, the results `[0,0,0,1,0]`.
Does the value of `1` still have a uniformly distributed chance of being at any of the `5` possible indexes in the list?

If you uniformly generate a `1` within a group of size $2^n$, and you than use only a subgroup of this group, the elements remain uniformly distributed?

Comment: There are a few problems with the problem. One (and the easiest to solve) is that $\{0,0,0,1,0,0\} = \{0,1\}$ so it is not a good idea to call these sets. I guess you can say I have $10$ boxes. When I open a box, I see a zero or one...

Comment: The other problem is to decide what you mean by "each element in the set has a probability $1/10$ of being equal to $1$." Going with my box example, is it "Given that you choose box $k$, the probability of you will observe $1$ is equal to $1/10$?" or is it something else?

Comment: I guess you have $10$ boxes, and you are given that only one of them has $1$ in it, and the rest have $0$ in it. In your experiment, you choose one of the boxes randomly (all boxes are equally likely), and you look what is inside. Then, the probability that you observe a $1$ is really $1/10$...

Comment: You now need to tell us your rule for removing those boxes.

Comment: I've rephrased the question as an example using bits, perhaps its easier to understand now. Thank you for your comments though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s how I understand the question:

> You have an $n$-bit string $b_1b_2\dots b_n$. For each bit you flip a fair coin to set that bit to $0$ or $1$, $0$ for heads and $1$ for tails, say. Each of the $2^n$ possible $n$-bit strings is then equally to be produced. Now for some $m\le n$ you look at the $m$-bit substring $b_1b_2\dots b_m$, and you want to know whether each of the $2^m$ possible outcomes is equally likely.

The answer is *yes*: each of the $2^m$ $m$-bit strings can be extended in $2^{n-m}$ ways to an $n$-bit string, so each of them occurs with probability

$$\frac{2^{n-m}}{2^n}=\frac1{2^m}\;.$$

Comment: I just noticed I never accepted this answer, but yes its what I was looking for. Thanks :-)